# Need a synonym for "don't care", as in Decision Tables or K-Maps (not for apathy)

Tags: terminology

I have more than one (non-technical) client who has been put off by the term "don't care" in a Decision Table context, even after I explain this is a technical term, and what it means. It just strikes them as a bit rude. When I search for synonyms I get results that have more to do with "apathy" than with this use of the term. (That is why I am not asking on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). This is also the source of the clients' reaction, I believe; it sounds too much like apathy, which is not what they expect from me as a consultant.)

Rather than fighting a silly battle I want to focus on the project. So I'd like to come up with a term that is clear to both technical & non-technical people, and is also inoffensive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might I suggest http://english.stackexchange.com/ ? Programmers aren't known for their command of the english language. The people on the English Language & Usage stackexchange can give more information than just looking up a thesaurus.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to explain to programmers why "don't care" doesn't sound right to clients, than to explain to English lovers what a Decision Table or K-Map is. Did you see my statement as to why I wasn't using SE's English site?

Comment: Your explanation in the original post seems to imply that the stackexchange can do little more than behave as a thesaurus, which is patently false. There are smart people -- even programmers -- on the English Language stackexchange. And this question is appropriate there. Not here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming something.

Answer (score 1):

So your users are going to see values and may want to select one that conveys that they don't care which value is ultimately selected?

I would suggest "No Preference".

EDIT: I might also suggest that you translate your request into layman's terms and try out the English stack exchange as suggested in the comments.  Those folks might be better equipped to provide you with a plethora of answers assuming they understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Would any of these work for you?

- Extraneous
- Unconnected
- Unrelated
- Not relevant
- Immaterial
- Inconsequential

Comment: Do any of them convey to you that this variable is in a don't care state for this business rule?

Comment: N/A, as user717554 suggested is probably most clear to both technical and non-technical users alike. Not relevant, irrelevant, and inconsequential would all convey that condition as well, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used NA for not applicable. It seems to already be in the non-technical vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Neutral -
Indifferent - 
No Opinion -
Unaffected -
Unconcerned - 
Does Not Matter